# How to run a previous command (that uses an alias) with sudo, both in command line and with an alias

Tags: bash, sudo, alias

(Note: This is *not* a duplicate question.)

On the command line, you can simply use `sudo !!` to run the previous command with sudo. However, how would this be done if the previous command uses an alias?

Likewise, if I wanted to use an alias to run the previous command with sudo, I could use one of the following (or other) options in the .bashrc file:

```
alias please='sudo "$BASH" -c "$(history -p !!)"'
alias please='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
alias please='eval "sudo $(fc -ln -1)"'
alias please='function _please(){ eval "sudo $(fc -ln -1)"; }; _please'
alias please='sudo sh -c '"'"'sudo sh -c $(fc -ln -1)'"'"''
alias please="sudo sh -c 'sudo sh -c $(fc -ln -1)'"

alias temp='sudo -s eval $(fc -ln -1)'

please () (
    my_source=~
    past_command=$(fc -ln -1)
    sd ${past_command}
)
```

I have tried every single one of those, and others, in an attempt to get these to work with an alias in the preceding command. I have tried expanding them with `shopt -s expand_aliases`, and I have tried using the `alias sd='sudo '` trick. They all work fine for normal commands, but sudo never knows what my aliases are.

I need to keep all customization options within my home directory.

If possible, I would also prefer to use an option like `sudo sh -c . . .` so pipes and redirects also receive the sudo power.

Edit: It has been found that using the `alias sd='sudo '` trick will work with `sd !!` on the command line, but it still won't work as an alias.

Comment: This is mostly to see how it can be done, as I've spent hours trying to figure this out. As of right now, I am settling for a keyboard shortcut in my .inputrc file with this line: `"\es":"\C-p\C-asudo "` This sets Alt-s to go to the previous line, go to the beginning of that line, and type "sudo ".

Comment: Creating a script with the command, and add it to `secure_path` is out of the question?

Comment: `alias sudo='sudo '` worked for my aliased command. i have na alias `vi='vim'` if i run `vi /etc/hosts` and then run `sudo !!` it runs the previous aliased command with sudo.

Comment: @BANJOSA Mmh, `vi` is a system command... are you sure that you are not just running `vi`?

Comment: yes it but i've aliased it to vim. I've done the same experiment with `alias nano='vim'`and `alias sudo='sudo '`and the executed `nano /etc/hosts` and afterwards executed `sudo !!` and it opened my hosts file with `vim`

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes, that is out of the question.

Comment: @BANJOSA So that does indeed work. Now how would I use an alias to do that command? I'd rather type "pls" instead of "sudo !!". But again, this is mostly to see if it can be done.

Comment: I've tried adding a new alias `alias please='sudo nano /etc/hosts'` where `nano` is an alias of `vim`and when I executed `please` is was working and asking the password for sudo.

Comment: @BANJOSA So why does that work when `alias please='sudo $(history -p !!)'` does not work? I still can't figure out how to get it to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definition of any alias inside (the shell started by) sudo.

In fact, it is a common security practice to remove environment variables and avoid aliases definition when starting `sudo`.

Let me walk you tru an example to explain:

Lets create a `/bin` executable (which only root could create) and define it as user executable:

```
# echo $'/bin/sh\necho "running $0 by $USER with $EUID"' >/bin/usercmd
# chmod a+x /bin/usercmd
```

That new command could be executed by the user with simply `usercmd` and by root with `sudo usercmd`

```
$ usercmd
running usercmd as isaac with 1027

$ sudo usercmd
running usercmd as root with 0
```

Both a user and root could run the executable.

And now lets define a very simple alias, and try it:

```
$ alias tcmd='usercmd'
$ tcmd
$ tcmd
running /usr/bin/usercmd as isaac with 1027

$ sudo tcmd
sudo: tcmd: command not found
```

There is no alias that sudo could use.

The only (general) solution is to extract the command inside the alias:

```
$ sudo sudo $(alias tcmd | sed 's/[^=]*=//;s/'\''//g')
running /usr/bin/usercmd as root with 0
```